# Running different React Native versions on the same dev machine

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a legacy project that I need to maintain on my development machine running 0.61 RN. However I'm starting a new project and would like to develop on 0.68 RN. I'm looking for a similar functionality as pythons Venv.

Can anyone point me to relevant resources.

Answer (score 0):

[Optional] Using a specific version or template
If you want to start a new project with a specific React Native version, you can use the --version argument:

npx react-native init AwesomeProject --version X.XX.X

[original link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)